# Boot sector gets corrupted after every power outage

Tags: windows-10, boot, bcd

One of my Windows 10 computer's boot sector gets corrupted and unable to start whenever a power outage happens. Then I need to use a Windows 10 installation USB stick to fix it. I know it can happen sometimes after outages, but it happens almost every single time on that machine.  For your information, I suppose PC is not using UEFI mode.

I don't think hard drive (SSD) is damaged, it's rather new and chkdsk reports no errors (I experienced similar thing happening on another machine too). And yes, write caching is turned off by me (in Device Manager).

What I don't understand is why Microsoft have to fiddle with master boot record all the time while the operating system is running. Or else it wouldn't get corrupted every single time, when almost nothing gets affected, isn't it?

This is quite frustrating problem because I run this computer without monitor.

Is there a solution for such a problem other than avoiding such power outages? Maybe something like "Unattended Windows 10 BCD repair USB"?

Comment: How do you determine that the boot sector is corrupted in the first place, and not something else in the process? And do you have anything to back the assumption that it's continuously being written to? (If either of those was true, it should be easy to check by comparing the sector's contents through time.)

Comment: I get an error on a blue screen regarding Boot Configuration Data. I'm not sure if that is different from boot sector, if so, the BCD gets corrupted so often. 

I'm not sure if Windows is writing to BCD all the time, but it the BCD file locked and cannot be accessed. So I assume it's open and somehow gets corrupted on a power outage. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: I doubt it's MBR or boot sector related. Also chkdsk does not tell you anything about physical health of a drive, it concerns itself with the file system only.

Comment: The BCD file is indeed different from the boot sector (for example, in that it is a file and the boot sector isn't). It _is_ usually open the whole time, as it is actually a small part of the Registry, but it is very rarely written to in normal operation ... and even then, it uses journalling to track operations in case of power loss, so problems such as yours should be very rare even if something does write to it.

Comment: @user1686 Thank you for the information. I see in this case the "problem" points to rather a bug in a driver somewhere or a problem in hardware (though SMART information of the drive looks fine, no errors or warnings on CrystalDiskInfo).  

I also run SFC /scannow "regularly" to pinpoint that problem but that's probably not related.

I'll try to change that Windows 10 installation to UEFI, and maybe it'll get better (if it won't completely mess up the system).

Comment: @ZeynelAbidinÖztürk Do you have separate boot & WinRE partitions? A dirty shutdown wouldn't result in the boot partition being corrupted since it's not in use at the time _(it's only used prior to loading the Kernel)_. My hunch is you don't have WinRE on its own partition, as when Windows experiences a dirty shutdown, a flag is set which can result in the OS trying to load WinRE at the next boot, however if your PC doesn't have a separate WinRE partition, and the filesystem of `C:` has been corrupted, it's not possible to auto-boot WinRE and is why it should be a separate partition

Comment: @JW0914 I had a recovery partition (I didn't know it's possible to not have it). But maybe that partition was damaged somehow. It sounds like what you said, but I'm not sure.  Today I updated the drive from MBR to GPT, and enabled UEFI boot. I still see a recovery partition and a new EFI partition. I'll see if it happens again. For testing, I tried pressing "reset" button one time and everything was ok, Windows started, but it may be just a luck. This drive was "cloned" from another drive during an drive upgrade, and maybe something gone weird during this.